# How to parse JSON as a AWS Lambda request payload using SpringBootRequestHandler

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

I have a AWS lambda written using Spring cloud function. My entry point is defined as .

```
public class LambdaController extends SpringBootRequestHandler<String, String> {

}
```

Then I have a class that implements Function interface the includes the logic for Lambda. When I am invoking this from Lambda with a test String (for e.g. "sample") it works fine, but when I invoke it using a JSON payload for e.g. with a SNS trigger I get the following exception.

`"errorMessage": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT`

Am I missing something?

Comment: This error is related to JSON parsing. Make sure that your response is valid JSON. Looking at an exception message I feel that response is not a valid JSON. Please edit the question and add the response.

Comment: This happens when the lambda is triggered via SNS topic, teh logic inside lambda is just to save records in DB and returns a String saying that it happened. I think SNS topic posts a request payload that is a JSON and somehow my lambda does not fully parses it.